# Populating Drop Menu from Array Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to dynamically generate a drop-menu list from an array via JavaScript. I'm getting close, but while I can populate the array elements into the Bootstrap-enabled drop-menu that appears on my index.html page, I cannot select those individual elements that show up as drop menu items. I need to edit my code so I can click on one of those elements and run my second function, that populates the selection to an input field.

First, here's my script to iterate over the array:

```
  <script>
    let select = document.getElementById("selectJob");
    let options = ["Job 1", "Job 2", "Job 3", "Job 4", "Job 5"];
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      let opt = options[i];
      let el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
    }

  </script>
```

And here's the second script I use:

```
  <script>
    function populateJobVal(val) {
      document.getElementById("selection").value = val;
    }
  </script>
```

And here's the drop-menu section in my HTML where I'm trying to use this:

```
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Select Job Type to Schedule
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="selectJob">
      <li>
        <a href="#" role="button" onclick="populateJobVal(selectJob)" class="btn btn-link">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Notice I am adding the "id" to the `<ul>` element. Should it be going elsewhere? I did try putting the "id" on the `<li>` element, but that makes all the array elements one clickable field, rather than each one being clickable.

Right now, when I click on the drop-menu button, the different jobs do appear. However, they are not individually clickable.

What do I need to edit in my code to make each element a clickable link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match what you have templated, you need to do the following:

```js
  let select = document.getElementById("selectJob");
    let options = ["Job 1", "Job 2", "Job 3", "Job 4", "Job 5"];
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      let opt = options[i];
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      a.textContent = opt;
      a.setAttribute('href', '#');
      a.setAttribute('onclick', 'populateJobVal(selectJob)');
      a.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-link');
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.appendChild(a);
      select.appendChild(li);
    } 
 
 function populateJobVal(val) {
      document.getElementById("selection").value = val;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Select Job Type to Schedule
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="selectJob">
    </ul>
  </div>
```